# How to limit a vector by two vectors added lengths by a max value

Tags: vectors

So while I am using this for a Game Engine, I believe this is more Maths related.

Just say I have 2 vectors *(in my case it is momentum and a value)*, I add them together and find their length from the origin. **I check if is bigger than a unknown max value.**

If it is bigger **I need an equation that will make the value vector smaller so it will not be bigger than the max value**

**Example:**
((momentum + value).length > max)
*if true make value smaller so that it is false*

I need the value vector to contain the same direction. So that you don't just limited one axis of the value vector.

My best bet is to normalize the value vector and *somehow find a way to multiply it by a value that allows it to answer my question*.

Oh and the vector has 2 dimensions

**Example with inputs:**

> momentum = (2, 3)
>
> value = (4, 1)
>
> max = 3
>
> .length being pythagorean theroem

```
((2, 3) + (4, 1)).length > 3

(6, 4).length > 3

7.2... > 3
```

*This is true so make value smaller so that when you put it in this equation ((momentum + value).length ) it will equal the max value (3 in this case).*

Comment: I think that, having gotten through a "first draft" of your Question, you should thoroughly edit it for clarity.  "I need it to contain the same direction."  What does "it" refer to?  What exactly needs to be preserved?

Comment: If the max was known then you would just scale each dimension by $\frac{max}{length}$ and the new length would be equal to the max. Since it's unknown, you might want to scale the vector incrementally by a really small amount, checking your condition each time. Once the condition is false, stop. If you want the direction of your vector to remain the same after scaling, make sure you scale each dimension by the same amount.

Comment: +hardmath Yep changed it

Comment: Try using an example to clarify what you want. Let's say max=$1$, value=$(1,0)$, and momentum=$(0,1)$. Do you want the result to be $(1,0)$, equal to the original value, because the vector can't move any farther in the direction of the momentum? Or do you want the result to be $(\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\frac{1}{\sqrt2})$, which is the unit vector in the direction of value+momentum? Or something else?

Comment: +FullofDill I scale the vector by a small amount because as I said it is in a game engine and it will use a lot of performance. I need an equation.

Comment: And there's no way to find out the max? If so then it's impossible to scale properly with 100% certainty unless you have more information. For instance, if you have a lower bound on the max value, it could be figured out.

Comment: +Chris Culter I did an example, hopefully that's what you wanted :)

Comment: +FullofDill this doesn't seem like something that should be impossible. There is a value that works and this is something I'm sure maths can do.

Comment: If you know something about the max value then it is certainly possible. When you say the max value is unknown, do you mean you know absolutely nothing about it? You don't know its value or a range of values it can be in?

Comment: +FullofDill Well the max value can be anything. I mean unknown as a variable.

Comment: You can just multiply each dimension by $\frac{x}{L}$, where $x$ is the max value and $L$ is the length of the vector before scaling. The length of your new vector will be equal to the max value, so your condition will be false.

Comment: +FullofDill ok I'll give this a try

Comment: @CowNecromancer `need the value vector to contain the same direction ... this doesn't seem like something that should be impossible` It *can* be impossible, unless you know more about the two vectors than you let on thus far. Consider for example *momentum* = (4,0), *value* = (0,1) and *maximum* = 3. No matter how you scale *value*, the sum *momentum + value* will have a length $\ge$ 4 > 3.

Comment: oh you're only scaling the value vector and not the (momentum + value) vector. my suggestion will not work

Comment: +dxiv I see what you mean, I can't really think well today because I'm a bit sick :(. I'll look into this after I try FullofDills method

Comment: @CowNecromancer Get well and be back. Btw the syntax here to "ping" someone in a comment is `@` (not `+`), otherwise the other party doesn't get a notification that they were mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p$ represent the momentum, let $x$ be the value, and let $M$ be the maximum. In the event that $\|x+p\|>M$, it sounds like you want to find a coefficient $t$ such that $0\leq t<1$ and $\|tx+p\|=M$.

If that's what you're after, then we can solve for $t$. Recall that the norm of a vector obeys $\|v\|^2=v\cdot v$, where $\cdot$ is the dot product.
$$M^2=(tx+p)\cdot(tx+p)=t^2\|x\|^2+2t(x\cdot p)+\|p\|^2$$
and so
$$0=t^2\|x\|^2+2t(x\cdot p)+(\|p\|^2-M^2).$$
This is a quadratic equation. As long as $\|x\|\leq M$ and $\|p\|\leq M$, it should have one solution with $t\geq0$:
$$t=\frac{-(x\cdot p)+\sqrt{(x\cdot p)^2-\|x\|^2(\|p\|^2-M^2)}}{\|x\|^2}$$
You'll want to double-check that by re-applying the quadratic formula yourself. Then test it on a few examples to verify that the behavior is really what you want!

Comment: Ok Ill give this one a go!

Comment: works nice but there's a bit of a problem that I should be able to work out :)